# Publish an Article on website, Medium and LinkedIn

Tags: seo

I need to get more exposure to my business,
Is it safe to post some of my articles on my blog, then publish it on Linkedin and Medium?
Would I be penalized for *duplucate* content? or is is just a myth?

Comment: We get these questions quite a bit. Without getting into the details, it is not wise regardless of canonical tags and any other mechanism to dilute your content between several sites. However, if you want to post a mini-post to other sites that then link back to your full content, that is a possibility. The days of content marketing in this fashion has been long over for quite a few years now.

Comment: @closetnoc I searched for a long time but couldn't really make a conclusion. So I guess simply copy-pasting from my blog to other platforms would do no good at best and even may harm my SEO ranking?

Comment: You are right. Content marketing in the past meant posting to other platforms. This never really worked and only made the other sites stronger. Even with canonical tags and attribitution, you are diluting your work. I have never seen where this works except to offer teaser posts that link back to your full content. Keep in mind that these other sites do benefit from your work regardless. Why not benefit your own site instead? Cheers!!